# Getter returning SegFault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, getter

Imagine this in the level.hh file:

```
Class Level {
private:
    int size;
    float** a_predefined_2d_array;
public:
    int GetSize();
    int SetSize(int);
    int DoSomething();
    int Load(string, int);

};
```

Imagine this in the level.cc file:

```
int Level::GetSize() {
   return size;
}

int Level::SetSize(int _size) {
   size = _size
}

int Level::Load(string str, int _size) {
   SetSize(_size);             //works fine!
   cout<<GetSize()<<endl;      //works fine!
   //basically loads everything to initiliaze the program. The point is that the above calls work fine!
}

//The problem is here!!!
int Level::DoSomething() {
   a_predefined_2d_array = new float*[GetSize()]; //SEG FAULTS!!!
   cout<<"size = "<<GetSize()<<endl; //SEG FAULTS!!!
}
```

Why is it that the GetSize() method segfaults?! It just doesn't make any sense to not work on other methods of the same class. 
I can also provide a link to the real project on Github, if that is requested. But I don't want to get to that point just yet.

Has anyone faced the same problem before? It's not a matter of wrong definitions or anything because I tested it out on the Load() method.

Comment: Looks fine so far (except for a missing `;`). I don't see any guarantees that size is set to a value though? Other than that I think some code, actually causing segfault, is missing. Note: you are also missing the definition of `a_predefined_2d_array`.

Comment: It will be helpful to diagnose the problem if you can post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try removing the `*` in `a_predefined_2d_array = new float*[GetSize()];` ?

Comment: What is the value of the variable "size" at the time of the exception? I assume it must have been some garbage value.

Comment: @abort It compiles fine. focus on the real problem. I named the variable "a_predefined_2d_array" because it is predefined which is not the important part. But I edited that in cause some one else gets confused

Comment: Whom are you to define what is the important part? You are unsure on what is causing it. I am focusing on the real problem, where is your guarantee of size being set properly? Using unsigned for memory sizes is definitely a good practice to prevent garbage sizes. @veda sounds plausible.

Comment: @Pavlos What compiler are you using? I ask because it *really* shouldn't compile like that. Also `Class` isn't the keyword, `class` is, so that's also confusing...

Comment: Could you add `cout<<GetSize()<<endl;` before the segfault to nail down the amount of memory it's trying to allocate?

Comment: @Pavlos [it does **not** compile fine!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab1024282bbcf407)

Comment: Please fix your question with code that actually compiles please.

Comment: @veda very interesting.. size has no value. it segfaults...

Comment: Also, please provide an example of the class in-use. Is anything supposed to be called before `DoSomething()`? Because of course it will segfault if it tries to initialize an array using an unitialized `int`.

Comment: @caps I said in the description that the actual code will be on github upon request.

Comment: @Pavlos the actual code, or simple **compilable** code based on it that provides the same example, should be in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://ideone.com/qa51JS) is an example with minimal changes (including simple zero-initialization) that compiles and runs on GCC.

```
Level l{};
l.DoSomething();
```

Comment: Interesting. I did not know that using `{}` would default-initialize member variables while not using it would leave them uninitialized.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Please take some time and take a look at my code on github. I provided in the description. I've added comments on the problematics file description to guide you.

Comment: @R2-Dequeue Can I ask you 1 more question? Can I contact you somehow via email or something?

Comment: @Pavlos If it's short I might be able to answer it here, or you can make a new question. You never know, someone else might find the answer helpful down the road.

Comment: @it's about base object stuff in c++. What I basically do is Data* d = new Data(); d->LoadData().. but the stuff from LoadData() do not get stored on d. So when I parse d to another method of another class for example, Algorithm* alg = new Algorithm(); alg->setData(d); the values from d are all 0.

Comment: @Pavlos Have you checked that `LoadData` is actually correctly reading in the values you want? Otherwise, looking at your code, I think that would need to be a separate question because I can't see anything obvious.

Comment: @caps OCD => Yep. Check subsection 8.5 of the standard for initializers. In this case, the braces imply list-initialization => value-initialization (8.5.4/3, second list item) => zero-initialization (8.5/8, second list item). When no initializer is provided (`T name;`), default-initialization is performed 8.5/12, which (again, in this case) gives the members indeterminate values. An implementation can decide to zero them if it wants, though, which would make everything work the same. [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) has the details summarized.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think my implementation must zero them by default.

Answer (score 0):

You do not get a segfault if you assign a value to `size` before calling `DoSomething()`.

[Live on Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d80bd9e43c3a14ac)

Comment: Yes, but a value is added when I call the Load method() which I do before DoSomething